# How to prove that E's limit point must be in E? (rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How to prove that E's limit point must be in E?

Thm 2.23 E's open iff E_c is closed.

First, suppose E_c is closed. Choose x belongs to E. Then x doesn't belongs to E_c, and x is not a limit point of E_c.......

Why it's not a limit point of E_c

Given the definition of limit point: For every r>0, there exist x' belongs to intersection of E and Nr(x) and x' doesn't equal to x.

Hope it could be explained in symbolic logic.

Comment: What was the _definition_ of "closed"?

Comment: Every limit point of E is a point of E

Comment: But now we are saying x is in E. Only E_c is closed.

Comment: Right. $x$ is in $E$ and $E_c$ is closed. So $x$ cannot be a limit point of $E_c$. Because $E_c$ contains all its limit points! That says if $x$ were a liimit point of $E_c$ it would be a point of $E_c$. Which it's not.

Answer (score 1):

First, suppose $E^c$ is closed. Choose $x \in E$. Then x doesn't belongs to $E^c$. 
$E^c$ contains its limit points.

If $x$ were *a limit point* of $E^c$, $x$ would be an element of $E^c$, since $E^c$ is closed. By contrapositive: if $x$ is *not* an element of $E^c$, $x$ cannot be a *limit point* of $E^c$.

So, $x$ is not a limit point of $E^c$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $E^c$ is closed. Let $x\in E$. Then $x$ cannot be a limit point of $E^c$ by definition. So in particular there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\cap E^c=\emptyset\Rightarrow B(x,\epsilon)\subset E$. This follows from the definition of limit point. Thus $E$ is open.

Suppose $E$ is open. Let $x\in X$ (the ambient space) be a limit point of $E^c$. If $x\not\in E^c\Rightarrow x\in E$, then there is a ball $B(x,\epsilon)\subset E$. But this implies $B(x,\epsilon)\cap E^c=\emptyset$, so $x$ cannot be a limit point of $E^c$. Thus if $x$ is a limit point of $E^c$, it must be in $E^c$, so $E^c$ is closed.

You can see that it's essentially the same logic in both directions.